# 先生 character etymology

Tags: kanji, etymology, false-etymology

先 looks like a teacher holding a pen, and 生 looks like a person sitting cross-legged with a pen, learning. maybe the symbols together mean someone who instructs someone else. Was this originally a Pictogram? just thought that was cool...

Comment: [https://okjiten.jp/sp/kanji180.html](https://okjiten.jp/sp/kanji180.html) and [https://okjiten.jp/sp/kanji33.html](https://okjiten.jp/sp/kanji33.html) (look under 成り立ち)

Comment: すごい、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

Note that 先生 does not strictly mean "teacher".  先生 is used as a title toward many types of superiours/leaders with some kind of expertise:  teachers, doctors, lawyers, politicians, even the pastor at my Christian church.  See [this link](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/sensei/) for more information about applicability.

> 先 - Means "previous" or "before"
> 生 - Means "live" or "born"

It basically means someone who has lived through a certain skill/experience more than you.

So no, as @sbkgs4686 linked in their comment, the etymology of the characters has nothing to do with pens, and only that of 先 is even related to a person.

Comment: ooooh! that is so cool dude! It's like this: 先 - Means "previous" or "before"
生 - Means "live" or "born". So it means like "The one who comes before the one that is more recently born"? right? wow. I saw the "pens" and thought of school, y'know. this is cool. And I know I just said what you just said, but this is so awesome!!! If you can't tell, I'm irrationally excited about this. lol

Comment: @ItsukiOokami: _"So it means like "The one who comes before the one that is more recently born"?"_ -- No, not quite; I think maybe you got confused.  It's literally "before, earlier, ahead of time + born", as in "someone who was born before you were" == "someone older than you" == "an elder".